# Call Javascript after iframe loads PDF data

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe

On click of a button we have an ajax call that does some calculations and commits data to the db. We disable the button the moment this call is initiated to avoid multiple submits.
Once this call is completed, we are creating an IFRAME using javascript and setting the src attribute to another page that serves the PDF data.

I would like to call a Javascript method that would enable the button again, once the PDF data is streamed to the browser. IFRAME's onload is NOT working fine.

**EDIT**

```
    $.blockUI({message: '<div id="loadingStatusDiv"><img src="loading.gif" /></div>'});
    $('.blockUI.blockMsg').center();
    var reportIFrame = document.getElementById("iframe");
    $('#iframe').ready(function() {alert('Done'); $.unblockUI();});
    reportIFrame.src = '${request.contextPath}/pages/downloadPdf.faces';
    document.body.appendChild(reportIFrame);
```

As I have mentioned above, the alert is displayed even before the PDF is rendered completely.

Comment: Can you post the code you already tried?

Comment: I have added the code snippet for your reference!